# Loading .dmp file to locate the error code,but the crash occurs in an unexpected place(in ntdll.dll)

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-2015, minidump

I write a funtion which access a NULL pointer like this:

```
CORRUPTDLL_API int fncorruptDLL(void)  
{   
    int *p = NULL;   
    printf("%d\n", p[0]);   
    return 0;    
}
```

and then call this function in main function just like this:

```
int main()
{
    fncorruptDLL();
    return 0; 
}
```

As expected,it breaks in the "printf" function and I can clearly see the crash place from the stack frame [crash place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fknDh.png).

Then I use "Windbg" to create a ".dmp" file and open it with VS2015,start to debug.It turns out a page which shows "No Source Available" [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTsDo.png) while I have already loaded the correct ".pdb" file and set the source code path like this:[set source code path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oStMx.png).

Why would this happen?I mean it didn't run into my function,I can just see the crash in "ntdll.dll"(from stack frame).But I am not familiar with assembly language.Does this ".dmp" file really work?

I used the "adplus" to monitor the excutable file

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\adplus.exe -crash -pmn winDgb_Test.exe  -FullOnFirst -o D:\VSproject\case-201710\winDgb_Test\Debug\dum
```

But when the program crashed,it didn't generate any ".dmp" file.What's the problem?

Comment: You created the dump file before the program did anything. You are looking at the "Okay, the program is ready to run" initial breakpoint.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes,it was my fault.I should have learned about how to use the "Windbg" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start debugging an executable and you start that executable under the debugger (in WinDbg: File / Open Executable), the program will run as short as possible and then stop at the [initial breakpoint (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/initial-breakpoint).

At this time, you can set up your debugger, e.g. define exception behavior, add breakpoints, load extensions, etc. When you're done with that, press `g` to let the program run. Then reproduce the crash, then create the crash dump.

Comment: I used the "adplus" to monitor the excutable file.But when the program crashed,it didn't generate any ".dmp" file.What's the problem?

Comment: @JimmyJack06: in the question you say `Then I use "Windbg" to create a ".dmp" file `. Now you create it with AdPlus. Please stick to your tools as long as you have one question. If you have problems with AdPlus, please ask a new question.